# Azure Cloud Service Usage

Tags: sql, azure-cloud-services

I want to use a database between two sides of a software product consisting of two separate applications:

> User side (Mobile)  --->  Database  <---  Admin side (Web application)

**Questions:**

1. Can Azure Cloud Services solve this problem or does a better solution exist?
2. Does Azure Cloud Services provide an SQL database in the cloud?

Answer (score -2):

1) Yes, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/sql-database/ 
2)[Connect two or more applications to the same database using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537675/connect-two-or-more-applications-to-the-same-database-using-hibernate)
this might help
3)https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/